# What does a circle under the head of a note in flute mean?

Tags: notation, flute

Upon reading the Modern Method for the Boehm Flute, I came upon this notation:

[image]

What does the circle under the head of the note mean?

Comment: This looks too asymmetric and smudged to be a proper symbol. It's probably a bit of dirt introduced during the printing process.

Comment: To test the currently popular "smudge theory," I wonder if it's possible to find a different copy of the same book and see if it also has a "smudge."

Comment: I haven't found another one online (other than IMSLP's), so it might be up to someone at a library to find out.

Comment: It looks familiar. I might have an orchestration book that uses that symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at page 19 of [this PDF from the University of Florida](http://ufdcimages.uflib.ufl.edu/UF/00/09/80/70/00001/notationperforma00will.pdf):

[image]

It definitely seems to be an indication for a natural harmonic. I know @Richard said a harmonic was notated differently, but perhaps he was thinking of an artificial harmonic? As for the lack of centering, I can see that as a typesetting issue.

Comment: The low D can't possibly be a harmonic on the flute.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, I'm pretty certain this is just the worst-placed and worse-shaped piece of fuzz to ever find its way onto a scanner, because:

1. The symbol is not actually centered with the note head.
2. The symbol doesn't appear to actually be a circle.
3. The symbol doesn't appear anywhere else in the book (as far as I can tell).

The nearest notation I can think of would be harmonics, but they are notated differently on a flute.